# How do I obtain a Golden Frying Pan?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is it strictly from MvM or is it for the upcoming Ready Steady Pan tournament participants only?

How can I get one of these beauts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first Golden Frying Pan was awarded 25 Nov 2013 to a user by the name of majine. When it was awarded, a notification went out to every user in-game, similar to the announcement everyone gets when giving/receiving the [Something Special for Someone Special](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Something_Special_For_Someone_Special). This player obtained it by simply completing an Operation Two Cities tour and got it as a random reward.

You could consider obtaining a Golden Frying Pan similar to winning the lottery, where your 4 tour of duty tickets is like a lottery ticket. Every time you complete a full tour, you have an incredibly small chance of obtaining one.

Comment: do you by any chance know the exact chance?

Comment: ha! i don't think anyone but the valve employee who designed it knows the answer to that question. If i had to speculate, it is programmed similarly to how weapon drops are designed, i.e. One drops, random amount of time before flagging the next one to drop. Except instead of this being per-account, it would be global.

Comment: Also, the second golden frying back was found about 12 hours ago.

Comment: If you want to follow how many frying pans are out there, a great source is here: http://stats.tf/item/1071/The_Golden_Frying_Pan

Answer (score 3):

It can only be obtained as random drop upon completing the Mann vs. Machine Two Cities tour.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying I can craft the Golden Frying Pan?

Comment: Wait, are you talking about the wrench or the frying pan? and how about a link to that tf2 wiki page?

Comment: I was playing tf2 last night and a guy got it as a random drop.

Comment: Okay, sorry I did my research wrong. After going through stuff again I guess you can ONLY get it from the Two Cities tour as an insanely rare drop. Sorry about that.

Wiki page here (now edited.)

http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Australium_weapons

Answer (score 3):

Another question *(closed as a duplicate)* asked if it's possible to buy a golden frying pan.  No one has answered that here, so I will attempt it:

There are two main places to buy in-game items for real-world money:  the Steam market, and from traders.

1. The [Steam Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Gold%20Frying%20Pan) is much safer, but it relies on people actually putting the item up on the market.  Since the seller will only get Steam wallet in return, it's much less likely you'll find one there.  As of 2015-12-16, there are no golden pans available on the market.
2. The best place to find someone trading a golden pan for Paypal is [tf2outpost.com](http://www.tf2outpost.com/search/258881370).  As of right now, tf2outpost has 13 golden frying pans for sale.  The current price is $2500-3000, so don't expect to find one for cheap.  Make sure to only trade with someone of *extremely* high reputation, and follow all the usual [trading safety procedures](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=434854781).  They will probably want the money sent to them ahead of time (possibly months in advance of the actual trade), to avoid chargeback scams.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd suggest that the Steam Market as not included in the answer: since there's a limit of about $200-300 USD (I forgot exactly which amount), it's highly unlikely that the Golden Pan would be on there since it would actually be worth somewhere over $2000.

Comment: @Texenox market cap is $400.

Comment: @ColinD Even so. Golden Pan is five to six times more pricey than that.